# Is it possible to copy on screen shot on Mojave?

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-mojave

I want to after command+shift+4 to screen shot, copy that image to do further work, so I don't have to click and drag the image from desktop, is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, but you need a double click. double click the image on the right-down corner of your screen and a simple command+c as it is previewed will work.
[image]